# how to create tree structure in neo4j with multiple relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

1.For example I create multiple Tweet nodes, these tweet nodes have id,reply_to id and retweet_id.  Assuming I have 6 nodes. The code below shows the nodes I create.

```
CREATE (n:Tweet:Node {id:'123', title:'A'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'234', title:'IT Team', reply_to:'123'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'testingTeam', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'234'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'588', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'testingTeam'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'kk', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'588'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'119', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'kk'});
```

2.Now I would like to create a hierarchy tree and trying to create two relationships. Here is the code I tried, but the relationship retweet can not be created successfully.

```
CREATE (n:Tweet:Node {id:'123', title:'A'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'234', title:'IT Team', reply_to:'123'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'testingTeam', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'234'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'588', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'testingTeam'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'kk', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'588'});
CREATE (cl:TweetLeaf:Node {id:'119', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'kk'});


MATCH (c:TweetLeaf)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:reply_to]->() or not (c)-[:retweet]->()
MATCH (parent:Node {id:c.reply_to}),(retweet:Node {id:c.retweet_id})
CREATE (c)-[:reply_to]->(parent),(c)-[:retweet]->(retweet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. None of the `TweetLeaf` nodes have a "retweet_id" property. And, although some *do* have the "retweet_to" property (which may be a typo), none of the corresponding values is "123". So, either way, your query can never succeed.
2. Also, you should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) to avoid creating duplicate nodes. This query may work better (once you have fixed above issue #1):

   ```
   MATCH (c:TweetLeaf), (parent:Node {id: c.reply_to}), (retweet:Node {id: c.retweet_id})
   MERGE (c)-[:reply_to]->(parent)
   MERGE (c)-[:retweet]->(retweet)
   ```